# Can we get x comment votes per y minutes, rather than one vote per 5 seconds?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, voting, rate-limiting

I quite often will read a thread of comments, and want to vote up a few of them. I vote one up, read the next few comments, vote up another and get a *giant red box*.

I've seen that "You can only submit a comment vote every 5 seconds" box far too often. Can I vote for 12 comments per minute, rather than 1 comment every 5 seconds?

Comment: I would also like this for comments posted. Too often I seem to get the "you can't post twice in xx seconds" message. If the second comment is short it is quite possible to come in under the time.

Comment: Yup, I tend to read through to then, and then apply votes at a rate of about 1 Hz. Or would if the bloody message box didn't get in the way.

Comment: I have also created a thread which argues that the problem is not the mechanism but the overkill in the error presentation.  
Problems with the current error:
- Brings up a popup.
- Displays the most visually noisesome red error I have yet seen on the site, total overkill.
- Remains open until you manually click close it.
*That thread is open for posting alternatives here*: 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39281/better-visual-indicator-for-time-limit-on-comment-upvotes/39283#39283

Comment: This is also a royal PITA when flagging obsolete comment sequences like "*Can someone...*", "*Done*", "*Thank you*"

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Yeah, this throttle doesn't make much sense any longer, so it will be removed in the next build.

You still have a combined 30 upvotes and deletes per day, though.

Comment: Dear Jarrod, would you mind posting a brief answer on [MO here](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1814/couldnt-the-comment-vote-rate-limitation-be-made-more-ergonomic) explaining how this got fixed? Thanks!

Comment: When did it ever make sense?

Comment: 2nd Tshepang's comment. I'm curious how this was important at some point (as throttles generally are), but isn't now.

Comment: It made sense in the very beginning of Stack Overflow, allowing [generic throttles](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1318059/3) to easily be attached to actions.  Now, most actions have daily limits and automatic flags that can warn of possible abuse.

Comment: Can you remove it for flagging too please?

Answer (score 45):

I don't think any such limit is needed. According to the answer here: [How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-do-comment-voting-and-flagging-work/17365#17365) there **is** already a limit:

> You get 30 comment upvotes per day

If the comment upvoting was unlimited, it would be very reasonable to limit the number of votes via limiting the rate the comments can be upvoted. However, with this limit, I see only one logical explanation for 5-second threshold: To **save the user from running out of limit too fast**.

I'd personally prefer to **decide myself** how fast I'm going to run out of that limit. The only thing I'd like to have is to be able to check how many comments I have already upvoted, and/or to be **informed** that I'm running out of votes (such as when upvoting questions/answers).

Comment: I forgot about the daily limit (thanks for the reminder). I never reached it myself.

Comment: I think it's one of the least known features of SO/SE.

Comment: It's annoying, tho. If I want to vote, then I WANT TO VOTE!

Comment: Just faced this issue. Comment voting quota over :(
Can't vote for another 11 hours!

Answer (score 17):

This would solve the problem that users currently cannot clean up their own obsolete comments.  If I am in a discussion of 4 comments each with a user on a question or answer I have posted, and if I incorporate the advice transmitted over the comments into my post, I still can't clean up my comments without being throttled. This is somewhat awful since there's some push on meta to get obsolete comments cleaned up better.

Answer (score 8):

The throttling is also a problem when reviewing the flags queue (10k-tools). An answer that is flagged as not an answer might have one or more good comments explaining why it has been flagged. I want to upvote the comments and downvote the answer to be able to vote for it to be deleted. Once I've decided the flags and comments are valid, I want to do all that voting quickly and then move on.