# Allow more than 1 comment upvote in 5 seconds

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, user-interface, rate-limiting

[image: Lets remove this]

This dialog box pops up so much that it's annoying. Please have it removed or allow something like 5 comment upvotes every 5 seconds.

At the least, make the box very small or replace the vote button with another graphic for 5 seconds.

Comment: +1 This bugs me. It seems strange that you can up vote answers as fast as you want, but not comments (especially when answers provide rep and comments don't).

Comment: agreed.  I have always assumed it was because there is no limit on the number of comment up votes one can cast, and this is a way to regulate the volume.

Comment: I don't think 5 seconds is entirely unreasonable to read a comment and give it some vague consideration that you agree with it.

Comment: I tend to read all the comments, and then go through and vote where applicable. The pointless 5 second restriction is **VERY** annoying.

Comment: It's pretty pointless considering it doesn't even change someone's rep. Unless Jeff has additional plans that I'm unaware of.

Comment: I hate the picture quality in this post. Is that a jpeg?

Comment: I hate that I don't have enough reputation on meta to fix the typo in the question.

Comment: I hate all this hate.

Comment: I like Cheesecake.

Comment: I wish I could downvote comments... if only someone suggested such a feature

Comment: Wait, there isn't a comment vote limit? I was pretty sure I maxed out once.

Comment: I posted something very similar, but marginally less drastic than allowing more votes - allowing 12 comment votes a minute, rather than 1 comment every 5 seconds (same number, just less annoying)..  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/can-we-get-x-comment-votes-per-x-minutes-rather-than-one-vote-per-5-seconds

Comment: This comment is random and should not be upvoted, even by someone just spamming up votes!

Comment: Like dbr above, I have also created a thread which argues that the problem is not the mechanism but the overkill that is the error presentation.  
Problems with the current error:
- Brings up a popup.
- Displays the most visually noisesome red error I have yet seen on the site, total overkill.
- Remains open until you manually click close it.
*That thread is open for posting alternatives here*: 
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39281/better-visual-indicator-for-time-limit-on-comment-upvotes/39283#39283

Comment: JFTR: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2148146#2148146

Comment: What is annoying is that I can't count seconds. Even if I count to five, I end up voting too early.

Comment: @DanielDaranas: I just keep clicking it repeatedly until it goes through.  "Inconvenience every legitimate user to prevent potential abuse by a few theoretical bad users" is terrible design.  Rate limiting to 3 votes per 15 seconds would be far better.

Comment: This has now been removed: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/can-we-get-x-comment-votes-per-y-minutes-rather-than-one-vote-per-5-seconds?lq=1

Answer (score 39):

Jeff's not explicitly stated here (*but otherwise mentioned other places*) reasoning, as far as I can tell, for declining this request:

- Less than 5 seconds would lead to a drastic increase in up votes for comments.
- This is bad, because

  - Jeff does not want comments to become too much of a platform for expressing one's opinion
  - (On Questions with many Answers) comments with some/high votes are filtered *into* the main page views, and those without are hidden, and need to be explicitly expanded to be seen.  Increase the comment votes too much and this functionality loses its value or ability to segregate the worthy from the unworthy.
- He has demonstrated this, somewhat cryptically, by up voting every comment before his in this question.
- Jeff just gets stubborn that way about certain points.  If the idea truly is decent, he'll come along eventually.  It's his website, he *can cry if he wants to...cry if he wants to.*

**The man has a vision, and extensive comment voting is not in that vision.**

Comment: Vision is great (and, it's worked out pretty well), but not explaining your decision reasoning in a site that claims to be driven by the community isn't really the best of ideas.

Comment: The reasoning was not spelled out, per se, but demonstrated with every comment in the question getting an up vote. Guess who did that?

Comment: Surely he can at least remove that large box (which you need to click to get rid of), and instead just disable the comment vote graphic for 5 seconds?

Comment: And, other the other hand, this site is not functional by implementing any and every change a user suggests that comes along.  As I noted, if it is deemed worthy it will come along. I am not even arguing against your idea, but rather the "Jeff doesn't care about us little folk" whining on this thread, as displayed by you and others.  SO has done a great job of listening to users, as you yourself seem to be aware of.

Comment: For the record: I like Cheesecake too.

Comment: But there already is a daily limit for comment votes.

Comment: "Less than 5 seconds would lead to a drastic increase in up votes for comments."  No it wouldn't.  It would just increase the rate at which they are upvoted.  I'm going to upvote that valuable comment no matter how many obstacles you put in my way.

Answer (score 21):

Why it bothers me? Sometimes I read a comment that is a good question, and, since it IS a good question, I want to read the next comment right away because now I'm dying of curiosity! Now, I'm satisfied, both a good question and a good answer, I want to upvote both!

A good solution that will prevent us being annoyed and abusers from ...abusing: Allow 3 comment upvotes in 15 seconds! (assuming the time from page load is >15sec, otherwise spammers/abusers get's 2 extra upvotes at no 'cost'.)

There, you have exactly 100% the same efficacy against spammers/abusers, and you do not annoy the poor curious readers with short attention spans for upvotes.

Comment: And when i say a comment that is a question i do not mean random question, but on getting more info from the original question.

Comment: I tend to process comments in two phases - read concentrating on the flow, and then vote. At the end of reading, I may know I like two or three of the comments. It seems silly to have to count off five seconds between casting the votes.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian An arguable point, depending on one's definition of "social network". For example, one of my research projects applied social network analysis to some communications among some computer science students and faculty. However, I don't see the relevance to the issue of allowing multiple comment upvotes.

Answer (score 18):

Along these lines, how about removing the restriction for those above 10k rep?  Or even some other number.

Comment: Better make this a brand new suggestion. I don't think anybody's going to pay much attention to something that is already declined. Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19874/change-comment-vote-limit-to-six-every-30-seconds Maybe if this question keeps bouncing back, Jeff will see how it is disproportionately impacting the user experience.

Comment: How about removing the restriction for those above 0k rep?