# Whatever happened to the 5 second comment upvote limit?

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, comments, up-votes

There used to be a limit on upvotes for comments ([Allow more than 1 comment upvote in 5 seconds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9811/allow-more-than-1-comment-upvote-in-5-seconds)). Today though I found a good question with a list of intelligent comments and quickly upvoted them all. Suddenly, I realised that this was something new. ***Has the rule changed?***

The five second message

[image: where did this go?]

**Update:** @studiohack *Merged my answer*

I would like to add that I hate the 30comments/12hour feature and I wish the powers that be at SO would consider moving to an unlimited karma supply with certain hourly or per minute restrictions to deal with misuse.

**Update: The 5 second message is back again! **

Comment: yup it is reproducible,

Comment: reproducible x 3!

Comment: I foresee a rush of Pundit badges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was an issue with the throttling on comment votes - everyone will now be constrained again :)

Comment: [citation-needed]

Comment: saw the 5 second message again today. I think, things are back to normal.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the rule has changed to 30 upvotes per day...A small change, but an improvement, users no longer have to count to 5 in order to upvote multiple comments, which is a nice upgrade...The post you mentioned makes no regard of the time limit, or not...it just mentions 30 votes per user, per day...

**My guess is that they simply removed the time limit, but left the 30 votes per user, per day in place, but many of us have never hit that ceiling (I think?!)...**

Comment: I hit the ceiling. Ow!(Rubs head). It would be better if the ceiling is 6 votes per hour or something like that. Hourly quotas or half hourly quotas are better.

Comment: it was always 30 upvotes per day, that has never changed