# Set hourly limits for Comment upvotes

Tags: feature-request, comments, up-votes

This is a (existing) feature (modification) request.

Please set hourly limits for comments upvoting instead of the current 30 votes/12hrs. Many of us SOer's derive happiness from distributing karma.

Please don't take this away from us.

This is a feature request. I posted a similar question today asking about ***[the 5-second-comment-upvote-vanishing-act](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66417/whatever-happened-to-the-5-second-comment-upvote-limit).***

Comment: -1 For *"Until recently there used to be a 5 second limit between two comment upvotes."*. Please **don't** bring that back!

Comment: @user[145673] (Martin Smith) removed that. Should I just remove this question and let them treat the linked question as a feature request?

Comment: (See [How do comment replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work))

Comment: I cannot edit that. I didn't know that @username triggers notifications.thanks! I thought any new comment in a post where they commented or posted earlier should trigger a notification. regarding my using the @user[id] format, I read a question regarding usage of @ and since user ids and post ids are unique we should be able to @user[id] @post[id] to autolink to them. can't find the article where i commented though. it's like using before it is actually usable. consider it to be a feature request.