# Why the 5s Comment voting limit?

Tags: discussion, comment-voting, time-limit

I find it strange that there's a 5 second limit between Comment votes. I sometimes read a few comments, and decide on the good ones, and then when voting it's like "damn, now I must wait".

Comment: [Status-declined]: [Allow more than 1 comment upvote in 5 seconds](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9811/allow-more-than-1-comment-upvote-in-5-seconds).

Comment: Just be glad the timer doesn't reset if you're too soon...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Completely agree.  I typically read all the comments first and then vote up 2-3 that I find useful.  (But have to wait 5 seconds between votes).

I am working to make myself vote after reading each comment.  But even then it normally takes me 1-2 seconds to read a comment (most are one sentence), which still leaves me with a 5 second warning if I vote two comments up that are close to each other.

Answer (score 0):

As I think, the idea behind having 5 seconds gap in comment voting is to ensure that you read a comment and vote it, then read the next comment and vote it. Invariably, you will atleast need 5 seconds to read one comment after the other.

The idea is to avoid people from simply voting on comments to gain some badges. So when user sees there needs to be 5 seconds gap, he is probably forced to wait for 5 seconds and inturn he might end up reading the comment as well... :)

In your case and to very much my case as well, I read all the comments at once and then go on the voting spree. So I like your point where you are bringing up this to the notice of SO developers.

Comment: Was there a badge back in 2011 for up voting comments? There isn't one today.

Answer (score 0):

On one hand you're right it might be irritating when you read them first.

But on the other hand, this is good protection against people who vote comments up without bothering to even read them. They will vote up the first, then give up when having to wait 5 seconds, or even better take that time to read the comment.

Bottom line, I would keep it like this and remember to vote up each comment after I read it, if it was good.

Comment: You could change the limit to something like "no more than 3 comment votes in 15 seconds"

Comment: @Michael - But how would you avoid people who simply vote for sake of voting. Even if such people get 3 votes at a time, they are fine right? They can move on to next question now. :)

Comment: @Sachin There are people who "vote for the sake of voting"? ...why? I guess you could limit the number of comment votes per day similar to post upvotes, if it's really necessary

Comment: @michael, the number of comment votes is already limited so the point @sachin makes is already somewhat handled.

Comment: @jzd Oh, cool. Apparently I don't comment enough

Comment: @Michael, yes I believe it is 30 just like normal votes.   (I do vote on comments more and have run into the limit several times, but not normally before I run out of normal votes).