# Why is there a 5 seconds limit for voting on comments, but not for voting on answers?

Tags: discussion, support, voting-limits

When you try to upvote multiple comments one after the other, you get a message saying "You may submit a comment vote every 5 seconds". I understand this feature is added for users to avoid simply upvoting on comments without reading them.

The same is not true when you are upvoting for answers/posts. So my question is - Why is this feature of time interval not implemented for upvoting multiple answers one after the other?

Comment: Hey, don't go giving the team horrible ideas!

Comment: @Gilles - I am just asking for rationale behind implementation only on comments and not on up/down votes. I am sure SE team would've thought about this ;)

Comment: Related questions: there [is an open question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79488/why-the-5s-comment-voting-limit) with regards to "Why is there a limit for comments". There's also a (silently) [declined request to remove that delay](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9811/allow-more-than-1-comment-upvote-in-5-seconds).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can you vote (up or down) every five seconds?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64091/why-can-you-vote-up-or-down-every-five-seconds)

Comment: It generally takes longer to fairly evaluate an answer than a comment, and answer votes have more affect than comment votes. So all logic would seem to suggest it should be the other way around if anything.

Comment: I've just seen a colleague upvoting both a question and its first answer in 3 seconds after opening it from Google results. Obviously he had only time to glance through answer and did not give it any thought. I think such behavior should be discouraged or forbidden too.