# Why must I wait between upvoting comments?

Tags: support, comments, comment-voting, thresholds

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why the 5s Comment voting limit?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79488/why-the-5s-comment-voting-limit)

Is there a reason that I must wait 5 seconds whenever I see two great comments next to each other? The effect is usually that I either only vote on one of them, or wait and lose another 5 seconds of my life (of which SE has taken enough already).

What kind of behaviour is it supposed to encourage? Am I using comment upvotes wrong?

Comment: Thanks, I missed that one searching. Also, the (ignored) [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9811/allow-more-than-1-comment-upvote-in-5-seconds).