# Deleting a comment (mine) shouldn't count as a comment vote

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, voting

I had an old question that I revisited in order to link it in a new answer. I noticed that in the comments Steven A Lowe had a funny comment that I -- at the time -- had responded to with "why can't I upvote comments?"

Well, of course, now I can.  So, I voted Steven's comment up then went to delete mine. I got the warning box that I can only submit comment votes once every 5 seconds. This seems like a bug to me. Deleting is not the same as voting.

Comment: I noticed this, too: adding a comment also sets vote timer.

Comment: Wish I could add a new tag..."bug-by-design".  Nothing wrong with the concept of `rate limiting`...just needs a tweak in implementation.

Comment: IMO if I'm cleaning up my own comments (e.g., removing obsolete comments) I should be able to do so without counting to five between each delete.

Answer (score 74):

I came here to log this as a bug and found this question - surprised it's still not addressed.

If comment deleting and upvoting are to be considered similar actions for the purpose of throttling, then I think the message to the user needs to be modified to better reflect what's happening. "You are only allowed one comment action every 5 seconds" or something like that. The message is simply saying the wrong thing, from a user-experience perspective.

Comment: But it was addressed - by Jeff Atwood on Aug 14 '09. I personally think it's the wrong answer, but it's not my site.

Comment: I think this only really bothers people who are [also bothered by the pluralization "bug"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694)

Comment: It sounds to me like the throttling engine (no pun intended) watching comments was poorly written in the sense it views all comment actions as a whole and not what the action is, therefore making it "difficult" to nail down the appropriate message.

Comment: A "comment action", however, is not entirely accurate, since comment creations are throttled differently. My guess is, as @bobobobo, alluded to, that nobody really wanted to fix the messaging to be longer and technically accurate, for minor benefit.

Answer (score 33):

Nearly 4 years later, and this bug is still in place.

**Simply change the message as follows**: "Comment votes, edits, and deletions may only occur once every 5 seconds"

**Steps to reproduce a bad message:**

1. Post a comment "this is a test" underneath another comment.
2. Upvote the comment above
3. Within 5 seconds, try to delete your test comment

This results in the nonsense message:

[image]

Comment: Have fun posting a comment `this is a test`, it's too short. ;)

Comment: This is patched; it's 2016 now, **7** years later!!

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος Yep, just tested it on your comment!

Answer (score 13):

The entire idea of rate limiting comment deletions is redundant. Why? Because we already rate-limit posting comments. Comment deletions are, in effect, rate limited as a result.

Rate limiting is intended to prevent DOS on the SE servers. However, this can't happen with comment deletions for two reasons: First, because there are only so many comments to delete, and second: because adding comments is rate-limited, inherently rate-limiting comment deletions.

I think this should be reconsidered entirely, as it's completely redundant in its current form (ideally removed).

Comment: hmm ... don't think that the delete limit is a directly related to the comment limit: posting a comment has 15s, while deleting is 5s

Answer (score 8):

As I've started to comment more often, I stumbled upon this "by-design" bug quite naturally.

The scenario is that I add a comment and, as the comment gets added and the comment section refreshes, I notice someone else made a similar or better comment. So I want to remove mine and upvote the other's.

For anything else, the throttling is fine as it is, but I honestly think an exception should be made for deleting one's own comment.

Answer (score 4):

Due to changes elsewhere, this is no longer really a problem (and the scenario described in the OP can no longer occur; both the vote and delete would be allowed within 5 seconds of each other). [In August 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238331/347902), the rate limit on comment actions was changed to "30 total comment votes and comment deletes per day"; however, the deletions and votes can occur arbitrarily close to each other in time. (I've verified that by upvoting and deleting a comment within 5 seconds of each other on this question.)

So although comment deletes and comment votes are still being treated as the same for rate-limiting purposes, it no longer really has any negative consequences.

Answer (score -11):

Deleting a comment is like voting to delete. Only it takes just one vote.

Comment: But voting for a comment is not like voting for a question/answer -- you can't delete anyone else's, just your own and you can only upvote a comment.

Comment: If you have a high enough arbitrary number, you can delete other people's comments.

Comment: @random -- I don't think I can delete anyone else's comments and my arbitrary number is pretty high.

Comment: Hmm, then it's probably just the mods that can "vote" to delete other people's comments.

Comment: It may be "like" it from the code's point of view, but that's the wrong point of view to be using. To a user it's a completely different operation.

Answer (score -45):

rate limiting requires this. Everything is rate limited for a reason; explained in podcast #65.

Comment: But it's a different thing.  That's like saying you can't submit an answer for 30 seconds after you add a comment.  Or is it the case that you can't do anything for 30 seconds after you do something?

Comment: I confess that I don't listen to the podcasts, but I do read your summaries.  I just had to wait 30 seconds to add this.  Yuck!

Comment: There's no question that throttling is needed, it's the messaging that's wrong...

Comment: Convenience link: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/podcast-65/

Comment: I wasn't aware there were podcasts...where can I see them/hear them if I don't have an iPod?

Comment: @JPM, there's a Flash-based player embedded on the blog post, as well as a download link for the actual MP3 file.

Comment: "rate limiting requires this".  ...more accurately: "this is the way we've implemented rate limiting...we consider voting to delete your own comment the same `type` of thing as voting on others comments.

Comment: I suspect the truth is somewhere between "Jeff wrote that code" and "ugh, don't really want to add another field to the dbase table".  Practical stuff.

Comment: This looks like a great example for codinghorror or thedailywtf.