# Repeated comment deletion shows wrong message

Tags: bug, comments, deleted-comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleting a comment (mine) shouldn’t count as a comment vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/deleting-a-comment-mine-shouldnt-count-as-a-comment-vote)

When trying to delete more than a single comment in less than 5 seconds (not a common ocurrence, I must admit), the popup reads (paraphrased) "You may submit a comment vote every 5 seconds" **instead of** "You can delete a comment every 5 seconds".

This is not a dupe of that question. The question in question states that deleting shouldn't be subject to rate limiting. This question refers to the message that pops up.

Comment: Dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/deleting-a-comment-mine-shouldnt-count-as-a-comment-vote (which is tagged status-bydesign).

Answer (score 1):

It's like voting to delete a comment. But you can only vote to delete your own. And you only need one vote to blast away the comment.

Comment: Yes and this is voting to create a comment, and this is me voting to press the X key. X!