# Is there a list of the time limits used on a Q&A site?

Tags: support, rate-limiting, documentation

Is there a page that lists the time limits adopted on a Q&A site?
For example, comment votes are possible only every 5 minutes; an answer can be accepted after X minutes the question has been asked.

Comment: These things are covered in the FAQ: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/ (and if they're not, they ought to be added)

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize how empty the FAQ was.  For the specific examples you mentioned, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/deleting-a-comment-mine-shouldnt-count-as-a-comment-vote/14427#14427 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/discourage-questions-being-marked-as-answered-within-an-hour-or-so-of-being-poste/44099#44099

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no aggregation of all of the time limits for all elements of the site. Each of them is instead listed in separate sections within individual FAQs, or as part of the original blog announcement for that feature.

You can find the general compendium of FAQs [in this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/the-official-faq-for-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user). Any not listed there will generally either have the [[faq] tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq) or the [[faq-proposed] tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq-proposed).