# flagging a comment counts as a comment vote, as does deleting a comment

Tags: bug, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleting a comment (mine) shouldn't count as a comment vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/deleting-a-comment-mine-shouldnt-count-as-a-comment-vote)

Submitting a flag on a comment, then trying to delete a comment within 5 seconds will result in the "you cannot submit more than one comment vote every 5 seconds" though neither of these actions are votes.