# Why does a comment flag count as a comment vote?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comment-flags, comment-voting

If I flag a comment and then attempt to upvote a *different* comment within 5 seconds, I get the comment box: `You may only submit a comment vote every 5 seconds.` Is this intentional? If not, I guess this is a bug.

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14185/172661

Comment: @KenWhite that question referenced deleting a question. I'm referring to flagging a question.

Comment: It has to do with a different comment action being counted. It had nothing to do with *questions* - it is specifically about a *comment*. I got there from [flagging a comment counts as a comment vote, as does deleting a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121472/172661), if that helps (it's **clearly** about a comment, and you can find my first posted link at the top of it).

Comment: Oh, well in that case...

Comment: The summary answer is every action on a comment is treated as a "vote", and every action is rate-limited.