# Why are votes on comments not shown in the "votes" tab of one's profile?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, comment-voting, votes-tab

People can vote on comments, same as on posts.  The "votes" tab of a user profile shows upvotes, downvotes, close votes, delete votes, and some others, but doesn't include comment votes.  Why is this?

Comment: Votes on comments are not really relevant, as they are not giving any reputation to anyone, my guess.

Comment: Can you please decide what you want this to be? A discussion, a feature-request or a support question? Because at best it is now a discussion but for a feature request (or support) I find it extremely incomplete and unclear.

Comment: @rene: I put it as those because I would like it as a feature, but I am asking why it is not here, and also that this is something to be discussed.

Comment: What do you think it would be better of as?

Comment: Ok, well is it better now that I have removed the support tag?

Comment: For the FR you need to add what you want to see. Do you also want to see the votes for deleted comments?

Comment: I remember a post where it was explained that comments don't have a full audit/history log, like there is for posts. In a comment-row there is only stored if the comment was edited and how many times it was voted on. That explains a bit why it isn't there, the data isn't stored. I'm still wondering how this feature will help, as in, what breaks your current workflow in how you want to use the sites.

Comment: @rene the data must be stored somewhere, otherwise we wouldn't see the  lit up arrow on comments we upvoted already. However, it is probably stored in a different place (Redis?) so fetching all of it per user is tricky and expansive, and in general not worth the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments are second-class citizens, as other answers have pointed out, so there is little benefit in tracking your votes on them.

Further, comment votes are special; [comment votes and flags are the same thing under the covers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174859/162102).  So showing comment votes in your votes tab would require that the code for that tab draw information from two different streams, post votes and comment votes, while also filtering the flags out.  That's not impossible -- your flags history shows some info about flagged comments without mingling in comment votes -- but it's messier.  More likely to lead to bugs.  And all that for a second-class feature.

(You won't be able to get the data from SEDE.  SEDE can show you the scores of comments, but the information about who voted is not in the public data.)

My recommendation is to accept comments for what they are: transient bits of information, humor, discussion, or opinions that appear, flourish briefly (or not), and then fade away.  At the rate comments are deleted (and for good reasons), your voting records wouldn't be very meaningful anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Because it does not matter if someone makes a good comment, so there is no merit in displaying the total number of votes against a comment.

People only comment because;

- They want the poster to add more detail (which get upvoted by people who also wish the main post has more detail but don't want/need to point this out again).
- Or because they have a lighthearted joke/comment to make about the post (which is likely the type of comment that gets upvotes).

So why does it matter when viewing someone's profile if they have received upvoted comments asking for more information (or have occasionally cracked a joke?)

Answer: it doesn't. I want to view a persons profile because they have provided me with some useful information and I want to see if there's anything else of use I can get from them. Comments are irrelevant to that.

Comment: So if I would have typed a joke here it would get upvotes?

Comment: On a more serious note: The OP is asking for this to be displayed on the Votes tab, which is private, AFAIK. So you're not going to see my comment votes anyway...

Comment: Are you joking, @rene?

Answer (score 0):

Votes on comments are irrelevant, as comments are irrelevant and ephemeral. You could lose those upvotes at any time.

However, if you want the data, then [there is a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/415462/get-all-comments-for-a-specified-user-in-a-descending-order-by-score) in SEDE, and it will work for any user's comments. It takes a bit of time to run, which may also explain why the data is not in the user profile.