# Incorrect error message on comment delete

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleting a comment (mine) shouldn't count as a comment vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/deleting-a-comment-mine-shouldnt-count-as-a-comment-vote)

I am trying to delete my comments on a question. Tried to delete two comments in quick intervals and got a message saying "You may only submit a comment vote every 5 seconds"

I think this message is not correct for the task I am doing. Here is screenshot.

[image]

Comment: +1 even though this is so trivial that no one would really care lol

Comment: It actually *is* a vote if memory serves - you are "voting to delete" your own comment.  Most actions in the SE system are considered votes.