# Comment deletion should not be rate-limited the same as comment votes

Tags: bug, comments, comment-voting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Deleting a comment (mine) shouldn’t count as a comment vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/deleting-a-comment-mine-shouldnt-count-as-a-comment-vote)

It is not uncommon to want to remove my own comments from a post, once the comments are obsolete.  However, this often leads to the

> ### You may only submit a comment vote every 5 seconds

notice.

1. This is annoying.  Is there any reason to rate-limit deletion of my own comments?
2. The error text is wrong, as I'm not submitting a comment vote. The first couple of times I saw the error, I assumed I had mis-clicked.

Suggestion:

1. Don't rate-limit deletion of comments.
2. If this is unacceptable for some reason, change the verbiage of the error message to be less confusing.

Comment: This request isn't new

Comment: Everything is rate limited in some way.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That doesn't mean it should be.

Comment: +1 half a year later, the issues still not solved (didn't see this before posting [the exact same question/bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/191856/159794)) and disagreeing with the duplicate which addresses only the second bullet, not the first