# Usabilities issues when deleting comments

Tags: bug, comments

on cleaning up comments, it happens that I want to delete several comments (f.i. after an excessive discussion about details of a post). Doing so quickly brings up the usual popup:

[image]

two issues:

1. I don't want *any* time limit on deleting my own comments
2. even if the powers-to ... ehh: community ... decides that there are reasons, the text is incorrect: I'm not *voting* to do something, I *do*

Comment: Why are you deleting many of your comments? That sounds like a strange behaviour?

Comment: @juergend why strange - it's quite usual when nudging a poster into improving his/her answer from unacceptabl to upvote-worthy :-)

Comment: @CodyGray darn ... should have seen the duplicate ;-) Though: it's only about the second, not the first issue - why is there a limit on deleting my _own_ comments?

Comment: I fail to see how it is not explicitly about *both* of the questions you asked here. And if you don't like that one, click on the links in the "Related" sidebar. This question has been asked bunches of times.

Comment: @CodyGray yeah just doing - the only reason I'm finding is _because everything is time-limited_, (in a comment to http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161853/159794 - which seems to be the exact duplicate of mine and also is closed a duplicate to the same as this is) that's not a good enough reason - I hate to be throttled, especially on clean ups ;-)

Comment: If there's an large number and they are all obsolete, just flag the post and mods can sweep them out en masse.

Comment: @jonsca thanks, but it's just a couple, typically :-) But: every 5 seconds a user has to wait is 4.99 seconds too much (if there isn't any _really_ good reason)

Comment: @kleopatra I weep when I think of all that The Throttle has provided for me.  But, I think this complaint has been issued many times, both for comments and the chat throttle, and neither has been changed.