# Misleading error message when deleting comments

Tags: bug, comments

When you have a few comments you want to delete and you delete them to fast you get the following message :

[image]

Which is misleading / incorrect. I'm trying to delete not vote.

Can you fix him ? :(

Comment: Ah its still a vote; its just a vote to delete that happens to be binding. :P

Comment: Yeah, I think this is because it's a single error message for all occasions; a better verbiage would be "You can only take an action on comments every 5 seconds."

Comment: @JoshMein clever. But I still think the message is misleading though :P

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes that would be way better.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/deleting-a-comment-mine-shouldnt-count-as-a-comment-vote