# Deleting comments quickly results in "cannot vote on comments for 5 seconds"

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

Strangely, when deleting a list of comments on my post (my comments) it says something along the lines of not being able to vote on comments for five seconds.

Since there was only three comments total (two mine, one another user's) even if I did vote, it wouldn't make sense because there is only one comment that I'm allowed to vote on, and since not being able to vote every 5 seconds implies that there was more than one comment that I could vote on, which is false.

I'm using the latest version of Google Chrome on Mac OS X, if that helps.

EDIT: Just found this question: [Deleting a comment (mine) shouldn't count as a comment vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/deleting-a-comment-mine-shouldnt-count-as-a-comment-vote?rq=1)

Comment: Any one-click-action on a comment is considered a vote.

Comment: So a flag and deleting comments are considered a vote as well? While it may be correct, it appears that it is flawed.

Comment: @alexy13 A flag actually does have separate wording.  It's just comment voting and deleting that are the types of "votes".

Comment: It seems like every week there's someone complaining that deleting a comment isn't voting on it. In addition to the duplicate, see questions 179239, 121472, 161853, 47412, 49268, 137592, 191856, 181549, 140891, 60327, and on and on... I agree the terminology is poor, but everyone is going to have to get over it, because for over three years it's been reported over and over again and is always status declined. I also have to wonder how people are asking these questions without seeing all of these duplicates before submitting. Kind of sad and nauseating.

Answer (score 4):

I was going to bring this up myself actually.  I don't understand what the purpose of the comment deletion time limit is.

The way I see it, If you're deleting all of your own comments on a particular thread, that's perfectly fine, especially when your comments have gone out of scope, or if you've found yourself involved in a discussion in the comments.

In this case, the 5-second rule is an annoyance.

And if you're deleting your comments across multiple threads, you'll probably be taking 5 seconds or more between deletions anyway, and it doesn't come up.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the behavior or motivation behind deleting comments, or that you're breaking some rule, I think it's just a method of rate limiting.