# Validation error when deleting comment

Tags: bug, comments

If I upvote a comment, then delete one of my comments immediately after, I get a message stating something like "You can only comment every 5 seconds".

Is this expected behaviour? It seems like my upvote and delete were both classed as comment submissions.

Comment: Comment operations might be consider the same way by S.E... But, yep, seems like a bug :-)

Comment: [Almost four and half year old bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14185/244282). Do we need to put some super special bounty only for someone who will resolve this.

Comment: That bug is [meta-tag:status-by-design] @VishwasSharma

Comment: @MaximeLorant no bug, both actions are considered "casting a vote" behind the scenes. One is upvote, the other is delete vote. :-)