# Changing text that is displayed when hitting the time limit for comment deletion

Tags: discussion, comments

**EDIT**: Let me break it down to something even simpler.

I understand that this is a [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) bug. I also understand that the deletion of a comment is implemented as a vote for deletion. The only thing I cannot get my head around is:

- Why can we not change the *text* that is displayed?
- Is it because it would be too cumbersome to make this change implementation-wise?
- Is it just low-priority?

The second and third question are simple yes-or-no questions that I think I can expect an answer to. I apologize if I missed something important.

---

I recently deleted two of my comments and got the following warning:

> [image]

Why is deleting my comment called a "comment vote"? Now, please read on before flagging it as a duplicate...

This is the same question as this one: [Deleting a comment (mine) shouldn't count as a comment vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/deleting-a-comment-mine-shouldnt-count-as-a-comment-vote). But unfortunately, nothing was done to fix the bug.

So, perhaps my question is rather: Why was this bug not addressed so far?

It has been around for a couple of years now and I'd really like to see a change to this misleading pop-up text.

N.B. I am not complaining about the time limit of 5 seconds. I am complaining about the *wording*.

Comment: Did you see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14427/218079) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/14186/218079)?

Comment: Of course. But those "answers" do not explain why nothing was done to improve the wording, in my opinion.

Comment: @Vishwas Sharma did you read my post before flagging it?

Comment: Afaik it's called a vote because it's implemented as a vote.

Comment: @MathiasMüller this bug is [status-bydesign](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/status-bydesign/info).

Comment: If there's a bug that hasn't been addressed, but there's an original report for it, you can place a bounty on that question.

Comment: @slhck I'd place a bounty on it if I had 17k reputation on meta. Besides, the answers there that are not downvoted have bounties of 400 and 100 already. But I'll consider deleting my question.

Comment: I know, but that probably just means the team doesn't want to fix it. It doesn't warrant posting another report to get attention. I can bounty it if you like.

Comment: @slhck Thanks - I appreciate your answer. I have edited my post to include this possibility (i.e. the team not wanting to fix it). I'd be glad if you put a bounty on the original report.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Perhaps retitle your question, if you are not interested in "why" but whether or not it can be changed.

Comment: @Bart You're right - the current one is not really accurate. What do you think of the new one?

Comment: Seems fair enough.