# Can we have a more relevant message when the deletion of a comment fails?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, error-message, deleted-comments

I had posted a comment on a question asking the OP to provide more information on the exact problem. Seeing that, the OP posted more information about the question and I decided to delete my comment as its purpose was achieved. But when I tried to delete the comment, I got an error message. This is the error message I got when I tried to delete that comment.

[image: Comment Delete Error Message]

The problem is not with the comment not getting deleted. I could wait for a while and delete the comment later, but the problem is with the error message which is displayed when trying to delete the comment.

> An error occured during voting

This error message for a comment deletion failure is certainly not the best.

So, can we please have a more relevant error message, something like

> An error occured while deleting the comment

or anything better the devs could come up with, when we the deletion of a comment fails?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14185/deleting-a-comment-mine-shouldnt-count-as-a-comment-vote :(

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Atleast the ones they reported had the word "comment" in the message, but here, it just bluntly says, "voting" :(

Comment: Well, technically speaking, you vote to delete the comment, same way you vote to close a question for example. Behind the scenes, the same code is executing, just with different parameters. So the error is totally correct from the code point of view.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - This is something new to me. Now it makes sense, atleast from the developers point of view, but from the end user perspective, it is clearly deceiving. To be honest, even I was confused for a moment if I had actually clicked on the little cross next to the comment or performed some other action which prompted this error message.

Comment: Totally agree, just explaining the root of this. :-)