# Comment vote throttling makes it annoying to clean up obsolete chat

Tags: discussion, comments, throttling

If I have a back-and-forth of say 4 comments each while refining an answer, I will then need to clean up my comments (presuming they are incorporated into the answer), then possibly flag my partner's.  But I can only do an action every 5 seconds.  Needless to say I have the attention span of a lab rat and am going to get distracted and post this question on meta.SO, and forget what comments I was cleaning up.

So yes, if we're serious about cleaning up our obsolete comment threads, we need to make this more expedient.  Possibly throttling at something like 5 comments every 25 seconds instead of 1 every 5.

Another solution is that deleting one's own comments should be throttled much more generously.  Isn't this ultimately limited by the number of comments I have?

*This is not a duplicate. There may be other solutions to this problem than the one proposed in the linked thread.*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we get x comment votes per x minutes, rather than one vote per 5 seconds?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/can-we-get-x-comment-votes-per-x-minutes-rather-than-one-vote-per-5-seconds)

Comment: I would upvote this as an answer to the duplicate as it adds an additional (and extremely annoying) dimension that hasn't been mentioned so far.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I was just thinking that.  Doing.

Comment: Just flag the parent post itself choose Other and ask for comments cleanup.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd not scalable per one of George Stocker's threads.

Comment: Deleting your own comment counts as a vote as well though @Sha, which is equally frustrating.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards actually probably better to leave this thread open for at least a couple days; there may be better solutions than the one linked as dupe.

Comment: Only you see the banner on top of the question saying it's a possible duplicate, no need for the bold beginning.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd didn't know that, was wondering the UX logic behind that.

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty recent change/improvement in the duplicate system. :)

Comment: Throwing in my thoughts here. Rate-limiting on comment deletion is redundant, as the number of comments to delete is finite, and the number of comments one can post at a time is finite. Full answer is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182719/206222).

Comment: Sorry, just because there's different solutions doesn't mean the question itself is not a duplicate... you can propose a new solution to the linked question.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd is throttling, limiting time between actions?

Comment: @Skippy throttling means regulating flow of things, see [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/throttling) - in this case regulating the flow of comments from a single user so he won't "flood" the site. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I need some guidance.. check your email - don't worry it's short!! hahahha