# Throttle comment flagging in the dialog box

Tags: feature-request, comment-flags, rate-limiting

When flagging comments I hit the rate limit often enough for it to annoy.  Each 'hit' forces a re-open of the dialog, select reason, hit the "Flag Comment" button - somewhat clunky.  Instead, could we keep the button greyed out until any pending rate limit period has expired?

[image]

To put it another way: only let me flag if I'm allowed to.

*Related: [Comment vote throttling makes it annoying to clean up obsolete chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182697/comment-vote-throttling-makes-it-annoying-to-clean-up-obsolete-chat)*

Comment: This is only tangentially related, but there's something wrong if you're flagging that often. If you're cleaning up an entire conversation, just flag the top comment and ask for the stuff under it to be deleted as well.

Comment: Normally I'd be flagging (soft deleting) a couple of obsolete comments, rather than a whole thread - I don't see what's wrong with that.